# How to insert a package declaration using an Eclipse template?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

**My template**

```
package ${enclosing_package};
${is:importStatic('org.junit.Assert.*')}
${i:import( org.junit.Test)}
public class ${primary_type_name} {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail();
    }
}
```

**What I want it to produce**

```
package com.example;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleUTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail();
    }
}
```

**What it actually produces** (package declaration below imports so compilation failure)

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

package com.example;

public class ExampleUTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail();
    }
}
```

I'm using this template in a blank java file. It seems a template always puts **import** statements at the top of the file, below the package declaration if there is one, which does make sense.

I guess my template isn't working because it doesn't 'know' I'm making a package declaration on that top line, so it just gets treated like any other line of code and puts it below the **imports**.

How can I get this to work - does a variable exist which explicitly does a package declaration, or is there another way?

Comment: I just tested that, and I also cannot get to the correct order. But why do you need that? I always create classes with the Eclipse wizard. Afterwards you already have a class template. Then you can add a JUnit 4 test method with typing "Test" and pressing <Ctrl>-<Space>. This template is built-in.

Comment: I want to use a single template to generate a lot of the boilerplate code for a unit test, in practice my template will be a lot more specific to the project I'm working on - imports for mocking frameworks, annotations, all that sort of stuff. Because Eclipse for some reason doesn't seem to let you define custom new class templates, what I do is generate a new class, delete all, then run this to generate all the template code for the unit test. There are obvious manual workarounds, I mean, I can just move the package declaration up myself, but it just seems this should be fully automatable

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate set of `Code Templates` for things like `New Java files` in `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates`. New files is the `Code` section, `New Java files`.

Comment: This would be the solution, except that annoyingly, Eclipse doesn't allow you to define custom code templates, for unit tests for example. That would be too sensible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, you cannot create both "package" and "import" template in a single code template. What you can do is, create two separate templates, as import and package both are two different contexts.